# Page loads too slow and selenium is crashing

Tags: python, html, selenium

i want to read some data, using a command, from an html page. The problem is that page loads too slow and selenium crashes after 4-5 minutes, closing my terminal. As a result, i can't proceed with command. Is there any way to avoid crashing or start reading without waiting?

I tried below to set delay time with no result:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
print("Loading page of air filters")
driver.get("https://b2b.fiba.gr/antallaktika/filtra/filtro-aera.html")
delay = 1000 # seconds
try:
   myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='product-name name']")))
   print ("Page is ready!")
except TimeoutException:
   print ("Loading took too much time!")
```

The command, which isn't executed is the following:

```
rdescs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='product-name name']")
```

Comment: Did you manage to load that page in your browser? That is probably the worst web design I've seen in ages.

Answer (score 1):

That is a huge web page, and slow as well, which will crash your system if you don't have enough ram and processing power (really bad design). If you want to scrape it, you can use Requests rather than Selenium. Here is one way to do it:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

prod_list = []
url = 'https://b2b.fiba.gr/antallaktika/filtra/filtro-aera.html'
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
soup = bs(r.text, 'html.parser')

product_cards = soup.select('div[class="product-meta product-shop"]')
for p in product_cards:
    title = p.select_one('h3').text.strip() + ' ' + p.select_one('h3').find_next_sibling('div').text.strip()
    origin = p.select_one('h3').find_next_sibling('div').find_next_sibling('div').text.strip()
    url = p.select_one('h3 a').get('href')
    prod_list.append((title, origin, url))
df = pd.DataFrame(prod_list, columns = ['title', 'origin', 'url'])
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
title   origin  url
0   ΦΙΛΤΡΟ ΑΕΡΟΣ FIBA - Κωδικός: FA-1012    MADE IN EU  https://b2b.fiba.gr/antallaktika/filtra/filtro-aera/filtro-aeros-fiba-fa1012.html
1   ΦΙΛΤΡΟ ΑΕΡΟΣ FIBA - Κωδικός: FA-1013    MADE IN EU  https://b2b.fiba.gr/antallaktika/filtra/filtro-aera/filtro-aeros-fiba-fa1013.html
2   ΦΙΛΤΡΟ ΑΕΡΟΣ FIBA - Κωδικός: FA-1140    MADE IN EU  https://b2b.fiba.gr/antallaktika/filtra/filtro-aera/filtro-aeros-fiba-fa1140.html
3   ΦΙΛΤΡΟ ΑΕΡΟΣ FIBA - Κωδικός: FA-124 MADE IN EU  https://b2b.fiba.gr/antallaktika/filtra/filtro-aera/f-a-a-124fiat-124-125lada-fiba-fa124.html
4   ΦΙΛΤΡΟ ΑΕΡΟΣ FIBA - Κωδικός: FA-1259    MADE IN EU  https://b2b.fiba.gr/antallaktika/filtra/filtro-aera/f-a-vw-transporter-bus-fiba-fa1259.html
... ... ... ...
709 ΦΙΛΤΡΟ ΑΕΡΟΣ - J.DEERE, M.FERGUSON FIBA - Κωδικός: FC-583   MADE IN EU  https://b2b.fiba.gr/antallaktika/filtra/filtro-aera/filtro-aeros-j-deere-m-ferguson-fiba-fc583.html
710 ΦΙΛΤΡΟ ΑΕΡΟΣ - J.DEERE, M.FERGUSON FIBA - Κωδικός: FC-584   MADE IN EU  https://b2b.fiba.gr/antallaktika/filtra/filtro-aera/filtro-aeros-j-deere-m-ferguson-fiba-fc584.html
711 ΦΙΛΤΡΟ ΑΕΡΟΣ - HITACHI, N.HOLLAND FIBA - Κωδικός: FC-585    MADE IN EU  https://b2b.fiba.gr/antallaktika/filtra/filtro-aera/filtro-aeros-hitachi-n-holland-fiba-fc585.html
712 ΦΙΛΤΡΟ ΑΕΡΟΣ - MITSUBISHI FIBA - Κωδικός: FC-586    MADE IN EU  https://b2b.fiba.gr/antallaktika/filtra/filtro-aera/filtro-aeros-mitsubishi-fiba-fc586.html
713 ΦΙΛΤΡΟ ΑΕΡΟΣ - MITSUBISHI FIBA - Κωδικός: FC-587    MADE IN EU  https://b2b.fiba.gr/catalog/product/view/id/3142/s/filtro-aeros-mitsubishi-fiba-fc587/category/11620/
714 rows × 3 columns
```

You can then follow those urls for individual products, and get more data.

Requests documentation: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Pandas documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/

And BeautifulSoup documentation: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/